# Google Hangouts very high CPU usage

Tags: linux, google-plus, video-chat

Whenever I use Google+ Hangouts I get extremely high CPU usage (generally 100% on all cores). There are some other threads on SU that have this problem, but they generally have rather low  nd systems. I have a Thinkpad T420 with a i7-2640M CPU. This certainly isn't a low end machine. When I reduce the size of the Hangouts window, things get a *little* better, but I'm still generally at >90% CPU usage.

I'm running Arch Linux.

This generally makes it so that video calls are choppy both in video and in audio, and other apps on the system are mostly unusable due to resource starvation. I think a similar problem also affects the commercial video conference software called Vidyo. I mention this because I know that the Hangouts uses the same codecs and protocols as Vidyo, so it may be related.

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot the problem?  Have you tried rebooting the system?  Have you tried disabling everything unnecessary and then adding them back in until the problem occurs? Or killing off processes to see if that helps?

Comment: What you have certainly is a low-end machine compared to current products.  The problem is indeed your cpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was that I had virtualization extensions turned off in the BIOS, which apparently matters for Hangouts. Turning this feature on (it was off by default, iirc) made hangouts work buttery smooth.

Comment: weird...I cant see why that made any difference!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I managed to reduce CPU load (Ubuntu 20.04 Intel i915 driver) by changing Google Chrome command line switches to:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --use-gl=desktop %U
```

Reference:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/chromium#Hardware_video_acceleration

Answer (score 0):

Type the URL: chrome://flags/ into Google Chrome's address bar, press enter.

An 'Experiments' page should load. I located the below settings and disabled them:

[visual description of controls, showing VP9 codec being disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhq4Z.png)

Running a test chat with check your audio and video didn't send my PC's fans running thus I presume worked.

```
sb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04 
Codename:   focal

lspci -vvvv
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4c53 (rev 01)
DeviceName:  Onboard Realtek Ethernet
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1515
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- 
Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- 
<MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0
Region 3: Memory at <ignored> (32-bit, non-prefetchable)
Expansion ROM at <ignored>
Kernel driver in use: icl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8b (rev 04) 
(prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
DeviceName:  Onboard Intel Graphics
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 1515
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- 
Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- 
<MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 141
Region 0: Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Region 2: Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```